# Routing in Rails 3 (upgrade from rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
map.resources :users, 
              :collection => {:access_history => :get }, 
              :member => {:change_access => :any }
```

Hello, the code above is part of the routes code written in Rails 2. I am having problem to convert this piece of code into an equivalent code for Rails 3. I would be glad if someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should be something like this :

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :access_history
  end

  member do
    match :change_access
  end
end
```

For more information about routing in Rails 3, you should take a look at the [routing official tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
 resources :users do
      get 'access_history', :on => :collection
      match 'change_access', :on => :member
 end
```